# progress bar for using java script unable to change color

Tags: javascript, php, html

Am using html to upload images and created java code to track uploading progress
ERROR is am unable to change color of progress loading color
 bellow is the code am using to upload images could u please help me
how do i change color of progress

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function _(el){
return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
var file = _("file1").files[0];
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file1", file);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "for.php");
ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
_("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
_("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
_("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
_("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
_("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
_("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
_("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" action="for.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"     style="width:100px;"></progress>
<input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

for.php

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){
echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

here is the demo http://sanojword.net23.net/PhpProject2/

Comment: So you are using JavaScript or JAVA?

Comment: sorry a mistake in that used ajax

Comment: I think it's not changing color, because there is no code to change background color of any element.

Comment: i used this method <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"     style="width:100px;color:red;"> but its not working

Comment: I think it's because progress bar is different for all browsers / OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress bar is different for all browsers and OS. It's unreliable to style it. But if you still wish to change it, [try this link](http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
   background-color: #eee;
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
```

Comment: i dont see any changes

Comment: @sanojlawrence What browser / OS you use?